# using stop-when in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I've been messing around with this program. It takes a number and adds 1 to it. 
I am wondering how exactly could you use `stop-when` here? For example, to make it stop at 5? I suppose a cond statement is necessary here. Thanks.

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

(define (my-tick n)
(add1 n))

(define (my-render n)
  (text (number->string n) 36 "silver"))


(big-bang 1 (on-tick my-tick 2) (to-draw my-render))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `stop-when` a predicate that consumes a world and returns true or false.

For more info, see the docs [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpuniverse.html?q=stop-when#%28form._world._%28%28lib._2htdp/universe..rkt%29._stop-when%29%29).

Here's a version of your example that stops at 5:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

(define (my-tick n) (add1 n))

(define (my-render n)
  (text (number->string n) 36 "silver"))

(define (=5 n) (= n 5))

(big-bang 1 (on-tick my-tick 2) (to-draw my-render) (stop-when =5))
```