# How to stop a conditional statement in racket without using error?

Tags: racket, conditional-statements

I am trying to implement the guess my number game in racket, and in a functional way, for educational purposes. My problem is that I have to stop the function with an error as in `(error "YOU GUESSED!")`. [The error function is what I could find in the racket documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html). Is there an errorless way to stop this conditional?

Note: I read about [stop-when](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18668773/664404), but I don't want to go into big-bang yet.

```
(define guess-my-number (lambda ()
  (letrec ([my-number (random 100)]
           [choices-left 7]
           [game (lambda (choices-left)
                (if (> choices-left 0)
                    (let ([user-guess (read)])
                      (cond [(> user-guess my-number) (display "That was too high!")]
                            [(< user-guess my-number) (display "That was too small!")]
                            [(= user-guess my-number) (error "YOU GUESSED!")])
                    (game (- choices-left 1)))
                    (display "Here ends the game!!")))])
    (game choices-left))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Do the `(game (- choices-left 1))` recursion inside the `cond` branches where you want to reloop:

```
(define guess-my-number (lambda ()
  (letrec ([my-number (random 100)]
           [choices-left 7]
           [game (lambda (choices-left)
                   (if (> choices-left 0)
                       (let ([user-guess (read)])
                         (cond [(> user-guess my-number) (display "That was too high!")
                                                         (game (- choices-left 1))]
                               [(< user-guess my-number) (display "That was too small!")
                                                         (game (- choices-left 1))]
                               [(= user-guess my-number) (display "YOU GUESSED!")]))
                       (display "Here ends the game!!")))])
    (game choices-left))))
```

Comment: I didn't knew that. Isn't this somewhat procedural? I mean: "if so, then first do this, and then do that".

Answer (score 2):

Chris' answer is perfect. This is really a comment -- except it's a bit long and you can't do code blocks in comments here.

The way you're coding it is a great way to understand how Racket works at a "low level", and is a very traditional way to code this in Scheme.

Another traditional way in Scheme is to use a couple features:

- The shorthand way to define a function.
- A named `let`, using the typical name `loop`.

That version:

```
(define (guess-my-number-v2)
  (let ([number (random 100)])
    (let loop ([guesses-left 7])
      (cond [(> guesses-left 0)
             (define user-guess (read))
             (cond [(> user-guess number)
                    (display "That was too high!")
                    (loop (sub1 guesses-left))]
                   [(< user-guess number)
                    (display "That was too low!")
                    (loop (sub1 guesses-left))]
                   [else (display "YOU GUESSED!")])]
            [else
             (displayln "Here ends the game!!")]))))
```

What's interesting is that this expands to almost exactly the same thing as your first version.

The `(let loop (guesses-left 7]) ...)` form is essentially defining a function named `loop`, much like your original one named `game`.  (In fact you could say `(let game ([guesses-left 7]) ...)`, too.)

One benefit is that it's not as deeply indented and doesn't march off the right side of the screen.

Finally here's a version that's a bit more "Racket-y" in making more use of `define`:

```
(define (guess-my-number-v3)
  (define number (random 100))
  (define (guess guesses-left)
    (cond [(> guesses-left 0)
           (define user-guess (read))
           (cond [(> user-guess number)
                  (display "That was too high!")
                  (guess (sub1 guesses-left))]
                 [(< user-guess number)
                  (display "That was too low!")
                  (guess (sub1 guesses-left))]
                 [else (display "YOU GUESSED!")])]
          [else
           (displayln "Here ends the game!!")]))
  (guess 7))
```

Although this is in more of a "modern" Racket style, it's not inherently "better". It, too expands to almost exactly the same thing as the original. In fact most Racket programmers would find all 3 styles easy to understand.

Anyway, all 3 versions "loop" by recursively calling a function, as you were already doing. The way to "terminate the loop" is simply... don't call the function again. That's the key point in Chris' answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I especially found it interesting that one could define a function with a let statement or solely as a conditional statement. I thought that I always have to use `(define function-name (lambda (variables..) (function body)))` syntax.

Comment: Well, in a sense you will always use `(define name (lambda (arg ...) body))` because the shorthand `(define (name arg ...) body)` is simply a macro that expands to it. :)  That's why it's taught early on. Also it emphasizes that functions are first-class values (like numbers) that you can give a name using `define` or `let`. But experienced folks usually use the shorthand (knowing what it's shorthand for).